# How to enable ribbon button in email after getting incident state in CRM 2011?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, crm

In CRM, I need to enable/disable a button in the Email form entity. The button is enabled if the parent entitys(Incident/Case) status is active otherwise its disabled.

My current setup:

1. Button is in Email Entity Form view ribbon
2. Button has a command calling some JS function (this works).
3. The command has an enable rule which calls `EnableEmailButton`
4. The enable rule expects the function to return `true`(enable) or `false`(disable)

JS:

```
var isCaseOpen = false;
function EnableEmailButton()
{
    var regardingObject = crmForm.all.regardingobjectid.DataValue;
    if(regardingObject)
    {
        var regardingObjectId = regardingObject[0].id;
        regardingObjectId = regardingObjectId.replace('{','').replace('}','');

        GetEntityById(regardingObjectId, "Incident", OnGotIncident);
    }

    return isCaseOpen;
}

function OnGotIncident(incident) {
    if(incident.StateCode.Value == 0)
    {
        isCaseOpen = true;
    }
}

function GetEntityById(entityId, entityName, CallbackFunction) {
    SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord
    (
        entityId,
        entityName,
        null,
        null,
        function OnSuccess(entity) {
            CallbackFunction(entity);
        },
        function errorHandler(error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    );
}
```

Since `retrieveRecord` is an async call, I cannot guarantee when I will get a response. But I need a response before the function returns the value of `isCaseOpen`.

How do I do this?

Basically I need to create a delay until I get an AJAX response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by editing the `SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord` function in the file Microsoft provides. I added an extra parameter to the function which lets the me decide if the call is async or not.

JS:

```
retrieveRecord: function (id, type, select, expand, isAsync, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  ///<summary>
  /// Sends an asynchronous request to retrieve a record.
  ///</summary>
  ///<param name="id" type="String">
  /// A String representing the GUID value for the record to retrieve.
  ///</param>
  this._stringParameterCheck(id, "SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord requires the id parameter is a string.");
  ///<param name="type" type="String">
  /// The Schema Name of the Entity type record to retrieve.
  /// For an Account record, use "Account"
  ///</param>
  this._stringParameterCheck(type, "SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord requires the type parameter is a string.");
  ///<param name="select" type="String">
  /// A String representing the $select OData System Query Option to control which
  /// attributes will be returned. This is a comma separated list of Attribute names that are valid for retrieve.
  /// If null all properties for the record will be returned
  ///</param>
  if (select != null)
   this._stringParameterCheck(select, "SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord requires the select parameter is a string.");
  ///<param name="expand" type="String">
  /// A String representing the $expand OData System Query Option value to control which
  /// related records are also returned. This is a comma separated list of of up to 6 entity relationship names
  /// If null no expanded related records will be returned.
  ///</param>
  if (expand != null)
   this._stringParameterCheck(expand, "SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord requires the expand parameter is a string.");
  ///<param name="isAsync" type="Boolean">
  /// Synchronous or Asynchronous request.
  /// 
  ///</param>
  this._booleanParameterCheck(isAsync, "SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord requires the isAsync parameter is a boolean.");
  ///<param name="successCallback" type="Function">
  /// The function that will be passed through and be called by a successful response. 
  /// This function must accept the returned record as a parameter.
  /// </param>
  this._callbackParameterCheck(successCallback, "SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord requires the successCallback parameter is a function.");
  ///<param name="errorCallback" type="Function">
  /// The function that will be passed through and be called by a failed response. 
  /// This function must accept an Error object as a parameter.
  /// </param>
  this._callbackParameterCheck(errorCallback, "SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord requires the errorCallback parameter is a function.");

  var systemQueryOptions = "";

  if (select != null || expand != null) {
   systemQueryOptions = "?";
   if (select != null) {
    var selectString = "$select=" + select;
    if (expand != null) {
     selectString = selectString + "," + expand;
    }
    systemQueryOptions = systemQueryOptions + selectString;
   }
   if (expand != null) {
    systemQueryOptions = systemQueryOptions + "&$expand=" + expand;
   }
  }

  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   datatype: "json",
   async: isAsync,
   url: this._ODataPath() + type + "Set" + "(guid'" + id + "')" + systemQueryOptions,
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.             
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   },
   success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    //JQuery does not provide an opportunity to specify a date reviver so this code
   // parses the xhr.responseText rather than use the data parameter passed by JQuery.
    successCallback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText, SDK.JQuery._dateReviver).d);
   },
   error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    errorCallback(SDK.JQuery._errorHandler(xhr));
   }
  });
 },
```